# ASP.NET - How to structure MVC3 models and views using the Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, domain-model

I am new to ASP.NET, so my question may be silly and influenced by years of using Java/JSF.

I want to implement a web application using ASP.NET with MVC3 and the Entity Framework 4.1. As it is a business application it should be secure by means of preventing data manipulation and by means of concurrency.

Thus I planned using optimistic locking which the Entity Framework supports. But when it comes to using the MVC paradigm and the options that it offers, I am not sure how to fulfill the security aspects named above.

**Example**

I have a domain model with an entity type "customer" which has the attributes

- ID (Database PK)
- Name
- Birthday
- Version (used for optimistic locking)

In order to prepare it for a view to edit its data, I additionally use a view model "customerView" with the following attributes

- Name

In the controller I load a specific record from the database, transfer the values to the view model and put it into a strongly typed view. This works great - the value is shown in the web form and I am able to post back the changes. As the view model does not include the ID and the version (resulting in not being part of the postback), I am not able to map the values back to the domain model as it got lost during the request-response-lifecyle.

Surely, I can add the ID and the version as hidden input field which I'd like to avoid as it enabled for data manipulation. Someone could change the ID or version before posting the data back, which might result in unwanted behaviour as I am not able to compare the data send back to the server with the one delivered to the web form (especially ID and version).

I think one way would be to store the data record/domain model (or at least the record's ID) I fetched before displaying the edit view in the session in order to avoid sending unwanted fields back and forth, though I know that this is not the best way and might influence application performance. What about using another session state then the default one, e.g. SQL Server? This would enable for saving at least one database operation as I don't have to load the record from the database another time in order to transfer the values from the view model. I can get the domain model record from the session and even might check for data manipulation.

I hope the example illustrates the problems I am facing.

Maybe there is an even better way to approach these issues. Maybe I am totally confused ;)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to race conditions the first question to ask should be: *What is the probability of a concurrent activity that actually leads to an invalid record?*

In your case: If you have a Customer with ID, Name, and Birthday I can't think of a common scenario where two concurrent users would edit the customer at the very same time AND enter different data. Why would one user enter one name or birthday and somebody else enter a different name or birthday at the same time?

What I want to say: In most cases the probability of the issue is negligible compared to the effort and loss of usability as well as performance that comes with locking and similar means of protection.

A very good article on the topic: [Race Conditions Don't Exist](http://www.udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/) by Udi Dahan

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said, this is just an example to keep things simple. I see your point, but often you have to keep in mind that even if the probalitity is small, a software's or company's reputation might be influenced badly when the issue occurs. In addition this sofware might be subject to audits, so I prefer to deal with these issues in before.

Comment: I understand your concern. I will probably sound like a politican, but I'm afraid, that the only answer to your question is: It depends. There is no best practice or canonical solution, especially when it comes to security, reliability and conformance. You might want to look into CQRS, an architectural pattern that inherently handles multiple users and can provide a fail-safe auditing mechanism. A good starting point would be http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/ and http://abdullin.com/cqrs

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include your ID in your view, there's no other way. As for data manipulation - you'll have to check (on every save) that user is allowed to modify object with this ID.

The same goes for version stamp, but in this case you don't have to worry about data manipulation, because there's practically no manually generate timestamp matching one in database, and if they don't match there'll be no edit, so you're safe. *Or* you can switch do other concurrency checking scenario, when you pass original values of every field being edited.